# Split Last two digit of a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to split the last two digits after a comma from the rest of the string and there is no success. This is a csv file. Rows with digits that end with 00 do not have a comma and those that are multiples of 10 only show one digit. I think I can work my way around that for now I need help with splitting digits after the full stop from the rest of the object.

```html
Values

2020-01-01,"00:00:00",1467.21

2020-01-01,"00:00:02",1467.28

2020-01-01,"00:00:04",1466

2020-01-01,"00:00:06",1467.06

2020-01-01,"00:00:08",1466.83  

2020-10-18,"19:55:04",3311.89

2020-10-18,"19:55:06",3313.03

2020-10-18,"19:55:08",3312.22

2020-10-18,"19:55:10",3312.29

2020-10-18,"19:55:12",3311.8
```

I needed them to be

```html
Values 

21
28
00
06
83
89
03
22
29
08
```

I used this code:

```js
import pandas as pd 
df= pd.read_csv('MESHS')

# dropping null value columns to avoid errors 
df.dropna(inplace = True) 
  
# new data frame with split value columns 
new = Values.str.split('. ', n = 1, expand = True) 

# making separate last name column from new data frame  
print(new[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('MESHS')

# dropping null value columns to avoid errors 
df.dropna(inplace = True) 
  
# data frame with split value columns and fill NaN values
df[['Values','New_Value']] = df.Values.str.split('.', n=1, expand=True).fillna(0)

# If you no longer need the original column, you can delete it
#df.drop('Values', axis =1, inplace = True)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                       Values New_Value
0  2020-01-01,"00:00:00",1467        21
1  2020-01-01,"00:00:02",1467        28
2  2020-01-01,"00:00:04",1466        0
3  2020-01-01,"00:00:06",1467        06
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Values'] = df['Values'].str.split('.').str[-1]
```

Comment: `2020-01-01,"00:00:04",1466` gives you `1466` which is not correct

Comment: I can deal with that and make a condition to replace all strings where `len() ==4 ` with 00. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Below code would help you

first, need to split the string values into numeric

so we can get the correct decimal values

then split based on the period operator.

```
df['numbers'] = pd.to_numeric(df["values"].str.split(",", n = 2, expand = True)[2])
df['values'] = df['numbers'].astype(str).str.split('.', n=1, expand = True)[1]
```

Output:

```
21
28
 0
06
83
89
03
22
29
08
```